# Prokofiev, Dance of the Knights, Measure 17

Tags: sheet-music, editions

[image: 3-Variations, Measure 17]

Heard Evgeny Kissin play Dance of the Knights on YouTube. Would like to purchase the version I heard. Purchased two sheet music versions, then discovered that there are many versions on the internet.

Question 1: How do I find/buy the version Evgeny Kissin played? (After some research discovered a YouTube video entitled Op. 75 included this performance. But the sheet music suppliers don't seem to reference Op. 75, etc.

Question 2: Which of the versions in the attached images is the "correct one?"

Question 3: Specifically, which bass clef version in the images is correct and how do I play it? Do I need to use my left hand AND right hand for the notes in the bass clef?

Answer (score 1):

The MIT version is what Kissin is playing: Prokofiev's arrangement of one of the pieces from his ballet *Romeo and Juliet*. After composing the ballet, Prokofiev arranged 10 of the pieces for piano ("10 Pieces from *Romeo and Juliet*") and published it as his Op. 75. The Knight's Dance is No. 6 from that collection (i.e., Op. 75, no. 6).

The bracket next to the upper two notes in the left-hand part means to play those with the right hand. ([See What does the L-shaped symbol attached to C5 and G4 on the top staff mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103442/70803))

A Google search for "[Prokofiev 75 6](https://www.google.com/search?q=prokofiev%2075%206&oq=prokofiev%2075%206)" will give you various editions of Prokofiev's arrangement.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you very much.  This is super helpful.